# How do I get live feedback in MVC or html based page?

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller

What is the best way to implement live feedback on a MVC based page?

Let's say if I edit a text box for number of items another disabled text box value for price will change.

Will it use Javascript or will it be similar to `validationFor` methods ?

If yes how will I go about doing this , if no what other methods would I use sorry for the noob question...

Comment: Will it use javascript? Yes. Whats your question exactly?

Comment: My bad bro , I I meant to say how would I use javascript to get the live feedback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider expanding your question and maybe include some code. Are you using razor to build your input element?

I love angularJS for this you can have an MVC input element and get instant feedback from it.

```
<input type="text" name="myInput" ng-model="theInput"> {{theInput}}
```

Angular binding will cause you to get instant feedback of exactly what's in your input element, of course you can just look at the input element too LOL. But in the above case myInput is your model variable ie Model.myInput, and theInput is your angular scope variable, ie. $scope.theInput.

Comment: Thanks will try that out and post my results right now I have the original scaffolded code that mvc5 created when creating a controller with views ... Will update later thanks :D